# jscrollpane in a cell doesn´t work jtable

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, tablecellrenderer

Surfing in the web, I found the way for using a JTextPane into a cell from JTable, only this way I can show the text centered, however, when I added a JScrollPane for showing a scrollbar when the text is longer than the cell height, the scrollbar is shown into a cell but it doesn't move only is shown but doesn't move.

[image]

I'm using org.jdesktop.swingx.renderer.DefaultTableRenderer of swingx framework, here part of my code:

```
//personal editor used in the JTextPane into cell, I  found it in the web

class MyEditorKit extends StyledEditorKit { 

    private StyledViewFactory estilo;
    private int maxTextHeight=0;

    public ViewFactory getViewFactory() {
        estilo = new StyledViewFactory();
        maxTextHeight = estilo.getVista();
        return estilo;
    }

    public int getAltura(){
        return maxTextHeight;
    }

    static class StyledViewFactory implements ViewFactory {

        private static View vista;
        private static int altura;
        public View create(Element elem) {
            String kind = elem.getName();
            String y = "";
                        y = elem.getDocument().getLength()+"";
            if (kind != null) {
                if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.ContentElementName)) {
                    vista = new LabelView(elem);
                } else if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.ParagraphElementName)) {
                    vista = new ParagraphView(elem);
                } else if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.SectionElementName)) {
                    vista = new CenteredBoxView(elem, View.Y_AXIS);                     
                    int x = vista.getDocument().getLength();

                } else if (kind.equals(StyleConstants.ComponentElementName)) {
                    vista = new ComponentView(elem);
                } else if (kind.equals(StyleConstants.IconElementName)) {
                    vista = new IconView(elem);
                }
                return vista;
            }
            return new LabelView(elem);
        }       

        public int getVista(){//It's not important so ignore it
            if( vista instanceof CenteredBoxView)
                return altura = ( (CenteredBoxView)vista ).getTextHeight();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
// Class which center the text into a cell

class CenteredBoxView extends BoxView {

    private int maxTextHeight=0;
    public CenteredBoxView(Element elem, int axis) {
        super(elem,axis);
    }

    protected void layoutMajorAxis(int targetSpan, int axis, int[] offsets, int[] spans) {

        super.layoutMajorAxis(targetSpan,axis,offsets,spans);
        int textBlockHeight = 0;
        int offset = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
            textBlockHeight = spans[i];
            maxTextHeight=(textBlockHeight>maxTextHeight)?textBlockHeight:maxTextHeight;
        }
        offset = (targetSpan - textBlockHeight) / 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < offsets.length; i++) {
            offsets[i] += offset;
        }

    }

    public int getTextHeight(){//It's not important so ignore it
        return maxTextHeight;
    }

}
```

---

```
//class that generate a JScrollPane

class TextAreaProvider extends ComponentProvider<JScrollPane> {

       private JTextPane area;
       private JScrollPane pane;
            @Override
        protected void configureState(CellContext context) {
        }

            @Override
        protected JScrollPane createRendererComponent() {
           area = new JTextPane();
           area.setOpaque(true);
           area.setEditorKit(new MyEditorKit());
           StyledDocument doc = area.getStyledDocument(); 
           MutableAttributeSet  center = new SimpleAttributeSet();
           StyleConstants.setBackground(center, Color.BLUE);
           //StyleConstants.setBold(center, true);
           StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
           doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), center, false); 
           //area.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

           int x = ((MyEditorKit)area.getEditorKit()).getAltura();
           pane = new JScrollPane(area);
           pane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);


           return pane;
        }


            @Override
       protected void format(CellContext context) {//Here is the format which will be shown in the cell   

                area.setText(getValueAsString(context));


        }



    }
}
```

I just put the code `tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(col).setCellRenderer( new DefaultTableRenderer( new TextAreaProvider() ) )` for generating a cell with a JScrollPane.

I'm tired of try a lot of things but I can't make that it works. 
I need a solution please!.